# Closing hole in top and bottom of scad object

Tags: openscad

How can I create an option to have the top faces be closed or open in an scad object?

I know I can change **ID=0** but that causes the length to change.  I want the same length and build of the object I just want to create an option to have the top and bottom faces to be open or close.

The scad library file can be found here. [Scad File](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3100539/files)

```
use <SnapConnectorLibrary.scad>
   
annularMale(length=10, ID=4.0, OD=4.5, baseRatio=1.35, toothDistanceFromEnd=0, toothMinWallThickness=0.5, tooth="ridge", toothLength=1.5,toothHeight=0.3, baseRelief=true, reliefRadius = 1, ridgeToothRatio = 0.75, toothOut = false);
```

Image of top and bottom faces I want to have open or close.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can fill the inner of the part with a cylinder.
With the intention of not to modify the library.

```
use <SnapConnectorLibrary.scad>
   
union(){
   cylinder(h = 10, r = 4.0, $fn = 180);


   annularMale(length               = 10.00, 
               ID                   =  4.00, 
               OD                   =  4.50, 
               baseRatio            =  1.35, 
               toothDistanceFromEnd =     0, 
               toothMinWallThickness=  0.50, 
               tooth                = "ridge", 
               toothLength          =  1.50,
               toothHeight          =  0.30, 
               baseRelief           =  true, 
               reliefRadius         =  1.00, 
               ridgeToothRatio      =  0.75, 
               toothOut             = false);
}
```

[image]